# why the swagger ui suddenly unavaliable

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

Today I facing a problem that all my services(more than 20 spring boot microservice) swagger UI could not access. The swagger UI works fine since last 2 years. When I am using this command to access swagger UI:

```
root@soa-report-analysis-zhuolian-7f5ff8fd66-lwbjh:/# curl http://127.0.0.1:11012/swagger-ui.html
{"timestamp":"2021-09-15T08:30:42.531+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/swagger-ui.html"}
```

I also tried:

```
http://127.0.0.1:11012/swagger-ui.html#
http://127.0.0.1:11012/swagger-ui/
```

both did not work. My swagger version info look like this:

```
api "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0"
api "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0"
```

And config resource like this:

```
 @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
```

SwaggerConfig:

```
package com.sportswin.soa.misc.config.swagger;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ParameterBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.schema.ModelRef;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.service.Parameter;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * swagger
 *
 * @author yangxinhua
 * @version 1.0
 * @date 2019-04-25 14:52
 */
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {


    @Value("${swagger.show:false}")
    private Boolean swaggerShow;

    @Bean
    public Docket createRestApi() {
        ParameterBuilder tokenPar = new ParameterBuilder();
        ParameterBuilder tokenPar2 = new ParameterBuilder();
        ParameterBuilder tokenPar3 = new ParameterBuilder();
        ParameterBuilder tokenPar4 = new ParameterBuilder();
        ParameterBuilder tokenPar5 = new ParameterBuilder();
        ParameterBuilder tokenPar6 = new ParameterBuilder();
        List<Parameter> pars = new ArrayList<Parameter>();
        tokenPar.name("token").defaultValue("70e624c1172ee53801ee8695c72030d5").modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header").required(false).build();
        tokenPar2.name("appCode").defaultValue("101").modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header").required(false).build();
        tokenPar3.name("requestId").defaultValue("2e0dddf9-17d9-42d9-8614-b44de17fe135").modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header").required(false).build();
        tokenPar4.name("clientId").defaultValue("7c54ff40-f11e-41c0-8d31-4b26d6569b5a").modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header").required(false).build();
        tokenPar5.name("x-request-info")
                .defaultValue("appCode=202;token=70e624c1172ee53801ee8695c72030d;clientId=7c54ff40-f11e-41c0-8d31-4b26d6569b5a;requestId=2e0dddf9-17d9-42d9-8614-b44de17fe135")
                .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                .parameterType("header")
                .required(false)
                .build();
        tokenPar6.name("appVersion")
                .defaultValue("Unknown")
                .modelRef(new ModelRef("String"))
                .parameterType("header")
                .required(false)
                .build();

        tokenPar6.name("platform")
                .defaultValue("WB")
                .modelRef(new ModelRef("String"))
                .parameterType("header")
                .required(false)
                .build();

        pars.add(tokenPar.build());
        pars.add(tokenPar2.build());
        pars.add(tokenPar3.build());
        pars.add(tokenPar4.build());
        pars.add(tokenPar5.build());
        pars.add(tokenPar6.build());

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .enable(swaggerShow)
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .globalOperationParameters(pars);
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("service doc")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("http://envelope.example.com/swagger-ui.html#/")
                .contact(new Contact("dabai", "http://envelope.example.com/swagger-ui.html#/", ""))
                .version("1.0")
                .build();
    }
}
```

What make me confusing is that:

- why suddenly did not work with swagger UI(return 404 when access the swagger-ui.html)?
- why suddenly did not work with all my service swagger UI, even some servcie did not change(restart or update)? the swagger have a cache and all services cache expired at the same time?

by the way, the config is work and the default show switch is open. I already debug to make sure the initial workflow works as expect. all the config has been initialed.